# In Composer force install when bundle requires older version of symfony2

Tags: symfony, composer-php

The title I think is pretty clear: how do I install a bundle that requires a slightly older version of symfony?

For example: I have the 2.4.* and the bundle requires 2.3.*.

I am sure that the bundle will also work for this version, but composer doesn't allow me to install it.

How can I resolve?

Comment: I could probably create a more suited example to your specific case if you'd include the concrete bundle you're talking about in your question. This way we could send a PR to the maintainer to have this fixed for other users without the need for a workaround in the future :)

Comment: I have many bundles in this situation. But what is the workaround?

Comment: Then please name them! I will provide a valid solution if you do. if those bundles do work under 2.4 ... i will inform the author and send a PR to have them fixed for the whole community.

Comment: Ok, but without naming names, can you tell me how to do it in general? 

How can I tell Composer "install anyway" bundle, without asking that requirement? Please tell me, i need...

Comment: You can alias the installed symfony to count as the older version.

Comment: ginolin ... i just don't understand why you aren't revealing the bundle's names?! All i want is to make sure the community can benefit from your findings afterwards. People put a lot of - usually unpaid - effort into writing these bundles and making them available to people like you for free. What's the problem in helping them in turn improve their software by contributing or at least reporting bugs? @Sven ... aliasing would apply to all packages and is therefore not a good idea. It could easily lead to other bundles that *don't* work with the older version of symfony break the application.