# how can I install package in composer without dependency

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am using `composer` with `symfony php`.

There is one `bundle A` which has dependency on Another `bundle B v 1.1`.

But I have the latest version of `bundle B v 2`.

Now I want to install `bundle A` without installing its dependency `bundle B v 1.1`.

How do I proceed ? Please suggest.

Comment: A quite similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21973786/1832745) was asked yesterday.

Comment: @nifr i think u know it. mine issue is with ladybug bundle. it requires ladybug 1.02 but i have installed its master version so composer is causing the error

Comment: If A requires 1.1 and B requires 2.0, then you have a dependency problem which you cannot solve. Either use 1.1 or 2.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**setup:**

The latest ladybug-bundle version is `1.0.2` but there have meanwhile been some more commits. It requires ladybug version is `1.0.8` which doesn't include the latest changes aswell.

**solution:**

An easy solution would be using an [inline-alias](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#require-inline-alias). Something like:

```
"require" : {
    "raulfraile/ladybug-bundle": "dev-master as 1.0.3"
    "raulfraile/ladybug": "dev-master as 1.0.9"
}
```

**alternative:**

You can define a package with the same name in your *composer.json* that includes the altered dependency.

Just copy the package definition from the original package, add the dist/source locations and edit the requirements.

composer will then use this new package definition because it picks the first match from all known repositories (packagist is always queried last).

You should choose a specific commit for the dist-zip. An example:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "raulfraile/ladybug-bundle",
            "version": "1.0.3",
            "require": {
               "raulfraile/ladybug" : "~1.0@dev"
            },
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle/archive/5c3739a881313f63f7b47ace49af5deeed211362.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            },
        }
    }
],
```

Now require `"raulfraile/ladybug-bundle": "~1.0"` in your *composer.json* and it will use the `1.0.3` version you defined yourself.