# Is there a way to tell Composer to install a package regardless of it's requirements?

Tags: composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I am working on a CakePHP 3.0 project which I want to update to 3.1-RC1. When I try do so I get an error:

```
Problem 1
    - akkaweb/cakephp-facebook dev-master requires cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.0.x-dev].
```

Now this plugin in question hasn't been updated in 6 months and I suspect it might work OK in CakePHP 3.1, so I would like to try it out.

How do I tell Composer to ignore this particular version incompatibility and proceed to update my CakePHP package?

I am aware of version aliases, but I only want the exception to be for the plugin in question, and not for everything else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I install package in composer without dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012397/how-can-i-install-package-in-composer-without-dependency)

Answer (score 0):

You should be frightened when you want to use a software that isn't maintained, hasn't released any tagged versions, and depends on developer branch versions of other important software. I wouldn't use this package at all. It will harm you in the long term, even if you made Composer install it.

If the current author does not respond to your contact attempts, you should be able to fork the project (in compliance with the license it gave you) and start maintaining the package by fixing the problems you have. Because that's what you'd have to do anyways when using unmaintained software. It will allow you to use this package in a much cleaner way, instead of coming up with a dirty Composer hack to make it install.